# The $\mathbb{N}_0 \to \mathbb{N}_0$ function that returns $n$ consecutive integers, skips $m$ consecutive integers, returns $n$... ad infinitum?

Tags: sequences-and-series

What is the $\mathbb{N}_0 \to \mathbb{N}_0$ function which returns $n$ consecutive integers, skips $m$ consecutive integers, returns $n$ consecutive integers again, and so on, repeating, *ad infinitum*?

Motivation: I was studying multiplication series and got curious when I found examples of this pattern. I found one such case when looking at the even multiples of $6$, e.g $\sum_{i=0}^\infty 6\cdot 2i$. The number on the $10$s place in the answer increment with $n=5$ and $m=1$.

$$
\begin{array}
\text{x} & \text{f(x)}\\
\hline
0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 \\
2 & 2 \\
3 & 3 \\
4 & 4 \\
5 & 6 \\
6 & 7 \\
7 & 8 \\
8 & 9 \\
9 & 10 \\
10 & 12 \\
\end{array}
$$

Comment: If it only skips a single integer each time, then $\lfloor x +\frac xn\rfloor$ does the trick (you can add or subtract multiples of $\frac1n$ in the floor function to change when the first skip happens). For bigger skips I think you need more fancy machinery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a formula for such a function, it is not hard to see that one is given by

$$f_{n,m}(x) := x + m \lfloor x/n \rfloor,$$

where $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ is the floor function (for $x\ge 0$, $\lfloor x/n \rfloor$ is the same as integer division in many programming languages).  The factor $\lfloor x/n \rfloor$ counts which "bracket" the input $x$ falls into (in your example the numbers 0–4 fall into the 0th bracket, the numbers 5–9 fall into the 1st, etc.).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Excellent!